# Sum of numbers divisible by 3 in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

Give two Prolog implementations to calculate the sum of first N numbers divisible by 3. For example: N=4 -> 30 (3+6+9+12).

```
sum(N,I,C,C):-!.
sum(N,I,C,R):-
    I mod 3 =:= 0,
    C1 is C+I,
    I1 is I+1,
    sum(N,I1,C1,R).
sum(N,I,C,R):-
    not(I mod 3 =:= 0),
    I1 is I+1,
    sum(N,I1,C,R).
```

I tried like this, but it's not a good way of thinking. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: (I am surprised the tag wiki entry for Prolog doesn't stress programming questions to be off-topic here.) `it's not a good way of thinking` Please state a measure for "quality of thought". (I remember `N`. How am I to interpret `I`, `C`, `R`?)

Comment: Programming is off-topic here. This question is very specific to Prolog.

Comment: I would just use the formula, assuming you can compute formulas in Prolog.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: If it is off-topic, why not close it?

Comment: @user21820 If viewed as a question on logic programming in general, it might be on-topic.